# F# Seq.sortBy in descending order

Tags: f#

I am fairly new to F# and came by the Seq.sortBy function however it is sorting my list in ascending order. How do I get it to sort in descending order using the Seq.sort?

For instance an example code would be...

```
let DisplayList =
seq{0..10}
|> Seq.sortBy(fun x -> x)
|> Seq.iter(fun x -> Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()))
```

gives me an output of 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, when I really want it to do it from 10 to 1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking at the other answers, beware unary minus and MININT:

```
let a = [| 1; -1; System.Int32.MinValue; 0; System.Int32.MaxValue; 1 |]

printfn "%A" (a |> Array.sortBy (fun x -> x))
// [|-2147483648; -1; 0; 1; 1; 2147483647|]

printfn "%A" (a |> Array.sortBy (fun x -> -x))  // uh-oh!
// [|-2147483648; 2147483647; 1; 1; 0; -1|]
```

I think you actually want negative-x-minus-one:

```
printfn "%A" (a |> Array.sortBy (fun x -> -x - 1))
// [|2147483647; 1; 1; 0; -1; -2147483648|]
```

for a wraparound integer type that spans `-2^N..2^N-1`.

Comment: Brian, I hope you don't mind but I added comments showing the output.

Comment: Just as a sidenote `-x-1 = ~~~x` because `-x=~~~x+1`. See [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). So you can shorten `(fun x -> -x - 1)` to simply `(~~~)` if you like.

Answer (score 25):

F# 4.0 (Visual Studio 2015) introduced `Seq.sortByDescending` and `Seq.sortDescending`

```
let DisplayList =
    seq { 0..10 }
    |> Seq.sortDescending         ' or |> Seq.sortByDescending id
    |> Seq.iter Console.WriteLine
```

See https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/ListSeqArrayAdditions.md

Answer (score 22):

Even shorter:

```
seq { 0..10 } 
    |> Seq.sortBy (~-)    // Unary minus
    |> Seq.iter (printfn "%d")
```

Answer (score 18):

First, let's extend `Seq` with a `sortWith` function same as List and Array have.

```
namespace Microsoft.FSharp.Collections
module Seq =
    let sortWith f e = 
        let e' = e |> Seq.toArray
        e' |> Array.sortInPlaceWith f
        e' |> Seq.readonly
```

Next, let's extend `Operators` with an often useful `flip` function.

```
namespace Microsoft.FSharp.Core
module Operators =
    let flip f x y = f y x
```

Now, we can leverage the generic `compare` function for generic (you can use this with any sequence of comparable elements) and safe (in regard to Brian's observation) reverse sequence sort.

```
{0..10}
|> Seq.sortWith (flip compare)
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm giving you +1 for the example of extending

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to wrap `System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderByDescending()`:

```
// #r "System.Core"
module Seq =
    let sortByDesc f s = Enumerable.OrderByDescending(s, new Func<'a, 'b>(f))

{0..10} |> Seq.sortByDesc (fun x -> x)
```

Comment: you have a typo: it should be Seq.sortByDesc (fun x -> x).  but actually, you can just use the 'id' function: Seq.sortByDesc id

Comment: Fixed, thanks. I just used what Mark used for consistency, but yeah `id` is good to know.

Comment: I have a library that does this for most of the linq chaining methods. http://jbtule.github.io/ComposableExtensions

Answer (score 7):

You can fix this by providing a negative key

```
let DisplayList = 
  seq { 0..10 } 
  |> Seq.sortBy (fun x -> -x)
  |> Seq.iter (fun x -> Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()))
```

Also it's a bit easier (and type safer) to use the `printf` functions for displaying text in F#.  For example

```
let DisplayList = 
  seq { 0..10 } 
  |> Seq.sortBy (fun x -> -x)
  |> Seq.iter (printfn "%d")
```

Comment: negative key doesn't help or work for `DateTime` unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

If you know, ahead of time, that you'll have a relatively small sequence, I think this is more readable...

`let x = seq { 0.. 10 } |> Seq.toArray |> Array.rev`

Of course, its not advisable if you got a potentially very large sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Solutions that use unary minus: `(fun x -> -x - 1)` and `(fun x -> -x)` don't work when you have unsigned types:

```ml
let a = [| 0uy; 255uy; 254uy; 1uy |]
printfn "%A" (a |> Array.sortBy (fun x -> -x - 1))
// error FS0001: The type 'byte' does not support the operator '~-'
```

Instead we can use the fact that `-x = ~~~x + 1` where `~~~` is a bitwise negation operator and thus `-x - 1 = ~~~x`. So the short solution that works for both signed and unsigned types:

```ml
Array.sortBy (~~~) // equivalent to Array.sortBy (fun x -> ~~~x)
```

Examples:

```ml
let a = [| 0uy; 255uy; 254uy; 1uy |]
printfn "%A" (a |> Array.sortBy (~~~))
// [|255uy; 254uy; 1uy; 0uy|]
let a = [| 1; -1; System.Int32.MinValue; 0; System.Int32.MaxValue; 1 |]
printfn "%A" (a |> Array.sortBy (~~~))
// [|2147483647; 1; 1; 0; -1; -2147483648|]
```