# Sort list High-to-Low in F#

Tags: sorting, f#

```
List.Sort
```

sorts a list from low to high - How does one sort from high to low? Is there some kind of library function for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# Seq.sortBy in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111448/f-seq-sortby-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a list of numbers:

```
list
|> List.sortBy (fun x -> -x)
```

The function `(fun x -> -x)` negates the number, therefore reversing the order.

For comparables in general, use `List.sortWith` with `compare`. Observe the ordering of `a b` in `compare`:

```
> List.sortWith (fun a b -> compare a b) ["a";"s";"d";"f"];;
val it : string list = ["a"; "d"; "f"; "s"]
> List.sortWith (fun a b -> compare b a) ["a";"s";"d";"f"];;
val it : string list = ["s"; "f"; "d"; "a"]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you looked at the linked thread [F# Seq.sortBy in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111448/f-seq-sortby-in-descending-order), there is a chance of overflow when you use `List.sortBy (fun x -> -x)`. To be correct, it should be:

```
List.sortBy (fun x -> -x-1)
```

In F# 4.0 (that comes with Visual Studio 2015 Preview), there are `sortDescending/sortByDescending` functions for this exact purpose.

You can use

```
list
|> List.sortDescending
```

or

```
list
|> List.sortByDescending id
```

See the comprehensive list of new core library functions at https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/ListSeqArrayAdditions.md.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List.sortBy` to sort by a custom function, and use the unary minus operator `~-` as such function in a compact notation:

```
let list = [1..10]
list |> List.sortBy (~-)
```